# SQL InnoDB Checking multiple columns for one LIKE value

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, myisam

I'm trying to find parts of a string (word,word,word,word) in one of the columns.

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LIKE '$string%' IN (col1, col2, col3, col4, etc)
```

but i get a fatal error telling me the syntax is wrong near LIK.

Is it possible to do this? and if so what am i messing up?

If I understood correctly an alternative would be to explode the string and do a foreach to check all of them separately?

```
$array = explode(',', $string);

foreach ($array as $string)
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MATCH (col1, col2, col3, col4, etc) AGAINST $string)
```

Comment: If you are only looking for words, see `FULLTEXT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do  a like for several  columns using or condition

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM table 
  WHERE col1 LIKE concat($string.'%'  or col1 LIKE concat('%','$string','%')
  OR col2 LIKE concat($string.'%'  or col2 LIKE concat('%','$string','%')
  OR col3 LIKE concat($string.'%'  or col3 LIKE concat('%','$string','%')
  OR col4 LIKE concat($string.'%'  or col4 LIKE concat('%','$string','%')
  OR etc.... coln LIKE concat($string.'%'  or coln LIKE concat('%','$string','%')
```

Comment: This gave me an empty array :( '$sting%'

Comment: this should check if any part of the string matches an item in the columns right? so if Pear is in on of the columns '$ApplePearBread%'  should find it?

Comment: the comment you provided is wrong you can check the content of the column not the column name  ... update your question ..with a proper data sample and the expected result .. so i can evaluate your real problem

Comment: I am trying to implement a search funtion. if a user inputs something like "apple bread pear pie" this is returned als a string: apple, bread, pear, pie.

Comment: ... why does enter post? so the string is "apple, bread, pear, pie". I want to find the best matching row in my table, meaning as many matching columns as possible

Comment: With like you can search  only for matching value ..  not for a list of string .. if you have a list of string eg:  "apple, bread, pear, pie" you should perform separated query ..

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE CONCAT(col1, ' , ', col2, ' , ' col3, ' , ', col4, ' , ', etc) LIKE '$string%'
```

Comment: can't you instead of using concat just do (col1, col2, col3, col4, etc)? since you are typing them anyway

Comment: I used ' , ' to add space and separator otherwise strings in the columns will be glued together and it may distort the result. But you can try it without ' , ' and see if it is ok